# Why have AWS decided to block ICMP by default on new EC2 machines?

Tags: amazon-web-services, icmp

From [Why can't I ping my freshly set up amazon web service EC2 instance?](https://serverfault.com/questions/511738/why-cant-i-ping-my-freshly-set-up-amazon-web-service-ec2-instance) it seems that the architects from Amazon's AWS have chosen to block ICMP by default.

Is there some official source stating their reasoning for that? I assume it is because of security but I'd like to be able to read their official stance on it, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That’s a bit of a misunderstanding - only *inbound **ICMP Echo*** is disabled by default and you can allow it in your Security Group if you need to.

ICMP is a whole suite of *Internet Control Message Protocol* packet types, most of them used for various traffic flow controls, etc. Those are not blocked because they are related to other traffic initiated by the instance. Only **ICMP Echo** is blocked by default because you don’t have control over who pings you and there is no need to have it enabled.

The reason is simple - AWS won’t let any unsolicited external traffic in unless you explicitly tell it to. And that includes ICMP Echo.